# Adding a label on a margin (instead of line number) in latex algorithmic package

Tags: formatting, algorithms

I would like to mark (e.g. with a `*`) a line in a pseudo-code typeset with the `algorithmic` package. I would like the label to appear on the left margin, instead of the line number. Is that possible?

I would like to have something like this:

```
  a = 5
  b = 7
* if a < b then
    ...
  end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `\marginpar`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\reversemarginpar % left hand
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE foo\marginpar{\hfill*}
\STATE bar
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

In two-sided document, you must test if the page number is odd using `\ifoddpage` from `changepage`, and choose `\reversemarginpar` or `\normalmarginpar`.